# Putting title on top of <div>

Tags: html, css

I am green at HTML, so I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to place a label on top of `addressBookWidgetDiv`that says Select Shipping Address and one top of the `walletWidgetDiv` that says Select Payment Method. So far everything I have tried puts the text between the 2 boxes, of course, I needed on top. I tried using `p` and `h1` tags with no luck.

These to elements show side by side.

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div id="addressBookWidgetDiv" style="width:400px; height:240px; padding-top: 50px;display: table-cell;"> Left </div>         
        <div id="walletWidgetDiv" style="width:400px; padding-left:10px; padding-top: 50px;height:240px;display: table-cell;"> Right </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? I am new at this so if this is elemental, please forgive.

Thanks.

Comment: stop saying forgive, we are here to help and guide you :)

Comment: I didnt get your question... Can you provide a picture or additional explanation of what you need

Comment: I think the 2 divs are showing up side by side because you are using display:tableRow for their parent.. So they will appear on same row

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what you want with paint and put that image here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to achieve a title above the "left" and "right" text? If so, I created a [jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nruak271/)

The HTML structure:

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div id="addressBookWidgetDiv" style="width:400px; height:240px; padding-top: 50px;display: table-cell;">
            <h1>Title</h1> 
            <p>Left</p> 
        </div>         
        <div id="walletWidgetDiv" style="width:400px; padding-left:10px; padding-top: 50px;height:240px;display: table-cell;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

And the CSS:

```
#addressBookWidgetDiv {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

#walletWidgetDiv {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

If you mean that the title does show up in the middle, then your `padding-top: 50px;`is causing the problem.

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do that by adding a `row` just above your current `row` containing the two `div`s as `display: table-cell`, take a look at the code you have to add -

```
<div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display: table-cell">Select Shipping Address</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">Select Payment Method</div>
</div>
```

**above the following code -**

```
<div style="display: table-row">
    <div id="addressBookWidgetDiv" style="width:400px; height:240px; padding-top: 50px;display: table-cell;"> Left </div>         
    <div id="walletWidgetDiv" style="width:400px; padding-left:10px; padding-top: 50px;height:240px;display: table-cell;"> Right </div>
</div>
```

and here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/radr3ver/